# Pivot large pandas dataframe in sagemaker

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have quite a large dataframe of few gigabytes and I am trying to pivot the dataframe. I keep running into memory error whenever I try to use

```
pivoted = df.pivot(index = 'column1', columns = 'column2', values = 'column3').fillna(0)
```

I have tried to use the chunks but I have hard time appending all the chunks back as one piece. Finally I have tried to leverage on the table format using the following code but I keep getting key errors.

```
chunksize = 10**6
filename = 'clean data.csv'
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')

for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    pivoted = df.pivot(index = 'column1', columns = 'column2', values = 'column3').fillna(0)
    #megalist.append(chunk)
    store.append('df', pivoted, format = 't', append=True, data_columns=True)
```

What with be a better way to pivot large pandas dataframe of few Gbs.

Comment: Why are you doing the pivot_table?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean to lad my dataframe into h5 and then pivot?

Comment: I mean, since memory is the issue perhaps you can solve the underlying problem without creating the pivot...